# Firestore android NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Getting the error in the firestore while querying collection with where equal to usage.

getting error UncaughtException: `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` as  in Line : `CollectionReference d  = fire.collection("list");`

code is

```
CollectionReference d  = fire.collection("list");

    d.whereEqualTo("data", "one").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e != null) {
                Log.e("Error : ", "Unable to load list : " + e);
                return;
            }

            List = new ArrayList<ListData>();


            for (DocumentSnapshot doc : snapshots) {
                final ListData l = doc.toObject(ListData.class);
                assert l != null;
                l.set_sem(doc.getId());
                List.add(l);
            }

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```

Log cat

```
UncaughtException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.w.a(SourceFile:30)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.w.a(SourceFile:44)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.n.a(SourceFile:1151)
    at com.project.activity.MainActivity.get_data(MainActivity.java:113)
    at com.project.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2673)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1508)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.x.<clinit>(SourceFile:30)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.w.a(SourceFile:30) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.w.a(SourceFile:44) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.n.a(SourceFile:1151) 
    at com.project.activity.MainActivity.get_data(MainActivity.java:113) 
    at com.project.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
```

Comment: Add the structure of your database.

Comment: I have the collection named as list and in that collection there are different documents in which I want to query all the documents where data = one

Comment: I am getting error on other activities too wherever fire.collection() is called

Comment: Can you please add the complete code of this activity.

Comment: Please also add a screenshot of your database and responde with @AlexMamo